# show/ hide ul for mobile device in responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on a website and for mobile device i want it to show and hide navigation when i click on image

```
<div class="mobile_header">
<div class="tab">
            <a id="tab" href="#">
                <img src="images/tab_btn.jpg" height="70" alt="logo" /></a></div>
              <div style="clear:both;"></div>  
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="first">About</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

            <li ><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

and this my css

```
.tab{ float:right; width:40px; height:40px; padding:20px;}

.tab img{ width:40px; height:40px;}

.mobile_header 
{
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #000;
    font-family: 'oswaldbook';
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    z-index: 111;
    text-align: left;
}

.mobile_header ul
{
    margin:0px;
    display:none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.mobile_header ul li
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

and here is js

```
   $("#tab").click(
function () { $(".mobile_header ul").fadeIn(700);  });

        });
```

what I want is to toggle the .mobile_header ul but its not working with

```
    $(function () {
                $(".tab").click(
function () { $(".mobile_header ul").slideToggle(500); },
function () { $(".mobile_header ul").hide(); }
);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions in the .click() method when you only need one:

```
$(function() {
  $(".tab").click(
    function() {
      $(".mobile_header ul").slideToggle(500);
    }
  );
});
```

[DEMO EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ho9excC3wGpLjEGAA3rf?p=preview)

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/click/